# Trying to build a concept hierarchy after Agglomerative Clustering

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am working on Natural Language Processing. I had to cluster the text data(words) using Agglomerative Hierarchical clustering to obtain concepts(clusters). My main problem right now is building the concept hierarchy. What I mean by that is representing the obtained clusters as a tree (also can be referred to as a dendrogram). After researching on scipy and sklearn libraries I could perform the clustering and observe the dendrogram. However, I couldn't build the correct concept hierarchy.

For example, if I have a formed cluster with words: car, vehicle, bicycle - the label of the concept should be Vehicle. In my current procedure I have Vehicle on the same level with car and bicycle and their root node remains unlabelled (scipy library dendrogram visualization). The point is the scipy library does not allow us to label the concepts directly, so I am looking for the ideas of how can I do it. I am very new in this field.

I already tried iterating through the labels and children in the output of AgglomerativeClustering method, however, I believe that the approach is not correct. Thanks in advance.

There is some code I tried to use:

```
`labels = agglomerative.labels_
 data_labels = {word: label for word, label in zip(words, agglomerative.labels_)}
 # Build the Concept Hierarchy
 concept_hierarchy = defaultdict(list)
 for idx, label in enumerate(data_labels):
    concept_hierarchy[label].append(idx)
 # Print the concept hierarchy
 for concept, data_points in concept_hierarchy.items():
   print(f'Concept {concept}: {data_points}')`
```